# ffmpeg: Endianness of audio samples

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, decoding, libavcodec

I use ffmpeg's avcodec to retrieve raw audio samples from music files in my c++ application. For files I test it on it appears that these files samples' endianness is little-endian, but I wonder if that will be always true for all files I'd try to decode (i.e. that comes from ffmpeg's implementation or at least it's architecture-specific since mine computer's architecture uses little endian). If not, I assume it would depend on particular file's encoding format. In that case how can I check which endianess applies for each file I'm decoding? I can't find any relevant information in the docs.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with FFMPEG. But there should be a struct which describes the format. Else it is not obvious how to interpret the data. Similar to the sample rate, the number of channels it should also describe the sample format. Could be 16LE, 16BE or float32 or something else. I would assume you could also instruct FFMPEG which format to output and does a conversion for you if neccesary.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch: "But there should be a struct which describes the format" - well, the thing is I have no idea if such struct exists, and if it does, which one is it. Also, instructing ffmpeg to do conversion just to ensure proper output endianness sounds like a waste of CPU. If possible, I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally ffmpeg always uses native endianness for audio samples since it makes it easier to perform various manipulations on the data (see `libavutil/samplefmt.h` file for some documentation on the matter); it is codec's task to convert to/from an appropriate endianness as dictated by file format. As a simple example of this: there is a family of trivial audiocodecs for reading/writing raw samples called `pcm_*`; e.g. there are `pcm_s16le` and `pcm_s16be`. On little-endian architecture `pcm_s16le` will do no conversion while `pcm_s16be` will swap bytes when decoding/encoding data.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrey said, FFMpeg internally decodes to native endianness. This is mentioned in the header file for libavutil/samplefmt.h

```
 * Audio sample formats
 *
 * - The data described by the sample format is always in native-endian order.
 *   Sample values can be expressed by native C types, hence the lack of a signed
 *   24-bit sample format even though it is a common raw audio data format.
```

It doesn't describe though *le or *be. The formats available are:

```
enum AVSampleFormat {
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE = -1,
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8,          ///< unsigned 8 bits
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16,         ///< signed 16 bits
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32,         ///< signed 32 bits
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT,         ///< float
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL,         ///< double

    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P,         ///< unsigned 8 bits, planar
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P,        ///< signed 16 bits, planar
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P,        ///< signed 32 bits, planar
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP,        ///< float, planar
    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBLP,        ///< double, planar

    AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NB           ///< Number of sample formats. DO NOT USE if linking dynamically
};
```

Generally you will get planar 16 bit signed samples.