# How to set audio format from an ffmpeg filter?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Is it possible to set the audio format just with an ffmpeg filter?

My usecase is programmatic usage, so if it's possible to do with filters, that would simplify everything.

```
# create sample s16 audio
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 8000 test.wav

# works
ffmpeg -i test.wav -y -af 'aresample=osf=flt,aformat=sample_fmts=flt' -f f32le test_f32.raw

# fails
ffmpeg -i test.wav -y -af 'aresample=osf=flt,aformat=sample_fmts=flt' test_f32.raw
# [NULL @ 0x56042863d980] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'test_f32.raw'
```

Comment: Your 'works'  command is how it should be done. `.raw` is not a generic extension so ffmpeg can't guess the format you want.

Comment: I thought that `aformat` could specify the output format instead of `-f`, couldn't it?

Comment: aformat deals only with format of audio samples in a frame. -f deals with output file format.

Comment: Is little/big-endian (e.g. pcm_s16le, pcm_s16be) only concerning output file format? What endianness is used within the frame? Is it always little-endian?

Comment: Ah, it seems my question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115629/ffmpeg-endianness-of-audio-samples

Comment: @gyan If you'd like to transform your comment into an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'works' command is how it should be done. `.raw` is not a generic extension so ffmpeg can't guess the format you want. `-f` needs to be set for output file format.

The aformat filter deals only with format of audio samples in a frame, and not with output file format.